# can I filter a spotify search by region

Tags: spotify

We're building an app that allows users to add songs to a special type of playlist and we're using the [search api](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/web-api/search/). At the moment, we're only targeting the US market, so it would be nice if we could pass in a region parameter of "US." The app we're building will be rolled out to several spotify markets over time, so this parameter would be part of a localization effort.

Is the ability to filter a search be region built into the web api?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't. You'll have to filter the search results yourself by checking the `territories` property of each item, i.e. the following (for [Madonna albums](http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/album.json?q=Madonna)).

```
...
{"territories": "AD AI AL AM AT AU AW AX AZ BA BG BM BV BY CA CH CY CZ DE DK EE ES FI FK FO FR GB GE GF GG GI GL GP GR GS HR HU IE IM IO IS IT JE KY LT LU LV MC MD MK MQ MS MT NC NL NO NZ PF PL PM PN PT RE RO RU SE SH SI SJ SK SM TC TF TR UA US VA VG WF YT"}}
...
```

If the `US` country code is in there, it's available in the US and so forth.